# Programatically reference ascending variable names (var1, var2, ... )

Tags: c#, jquery

I'm currently coding a project that can take up to 200 entries of a specific product, as determined by user input.  Basically, my GUI loads, and I use jQuery to dynamically build the entries whenever there is a change to the amount field.  When using jQuery, I simply give each of them ids in the form of variable1, variable2, ...., variableX (where X is the amount of entries indicated).  Small snippet of code to clarify:

```
for(var i = 1;i <= amount_selected; i++) { 
    $('table_name tr:last').after('<tr><td><input type="text" id="variable' + i + '"></td></tr>');
}
```

Now when I try to move to the back end, I'm trying to reference these variable names by putting them in a list.  I went ahead and put them in a list of HtmlInputText, to call the Variable names from the list itself.  (This would save having to call all (up to 200) methods manually, which is really not an option).

So what I did (in C#) was:

```
List<HtmlInputText> listvar = new List<HtmlInputText>();
for(int i = 1; i <= amount_selected; i++) { 
    string j = "variable" + Convert.ToString(i);
    HtmlInputText x = j; 
    listvar.Add((x));
    samplemethod(listvar[i]);
}
```

But it's not working at all.  Does anyone have any ideas as to how this would be done, without doing so manually?  I know my logic might be completely off, but hopefully this illustrates at least what I'm attempting to do.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `"variable"` instead of `'variable'` for a C# string?

Comment: @Daniel - I could use an Array, but that still wouldn't solve the problems that I'm running into, unless there is a way to put the ids of each input field (on the GUI) as part of an array, which, admittedly, I haven't even looked into. 

@kei - Consider that a 'derp' moment.  It's double quotes in my actual program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming these inputs are in a form?  If you're submitting then you can access the text boxes from the `Request` object:

```
List<string> results = new List<string>();
for (int i = 1; i <= amount_selected; i++)
{
    string s = String.Format("{0}", Request.Form["variable" + Convert.ToString(i)]);
    results.Add(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do $("#variable" + Convert.ToString(i)).val()